# With mysql what locks are placed during compression

Tags: mysql, locking, compression

On a 5.5.23 system (we'll soon upgrade, I promise! :-) ) I need to enable compression on a large table. I'll do it with an "alter table" command. The question is, during the considerable time it will take to complete, will there be any read/write locks on that table?

My research indicates that reads will be possible, but not writes. And for a very  brief period at the end of the operation, even reads will not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

On most database system, as soon as you call `ALTER TABLE` an exclusive lock needs to be placed on the until the operation is complete.

This would prevent reads as well as writes, while the table is being modified.